# how to obtain elasticsearch performance optimization in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire, elastica

I have elasticsearch application .how can I make its performance at the optimize level ,I know this is some thing verge question but My client ask me to do so..Even my application is working smoothly on my local but in production the scenario may be different due to number of query request **can any one suggest me which direction i have to think**,I need the strong direction so please give me reply thanks
I am using tire/karmi with ES data store in my Ruby on rails application. 
I have

> > index.number_of_shards: 5
> >
> > index.number_of_replicas: 1
> >
> > node: 1

Answer (score 1):

To optimize ES, there is something we can do

1.use less no of shards ( if you have more no if shards Den it performs map reduce to merge results from different shards)

2 . choose in index.store.type. By default it store index as simple file system. Use niofs for Linux and mmaps for Windows

1. Use appropriate queries. Don include more wildcard queries, use filters as much as you can.
2. Use thrift protocol..  Because it converts data in to binary so easy to transfer and faster too..